# Spring app from eclipse to intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, intellij-idea

I have a Spring application that i did not started to build, these dudes made it old school way without maven or gradle support in eclipse.

I want to work on it in IntelliJ Idea, importing the project gives me the following errors:

Idea Event Log:

```
12:13:36 PM Unknown Natures Detected
            Imported projects contain unknown natures:
            org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature
            org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature
            org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature
            org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature
            Some settings may be lost after import.
```

Also when trying to build:

```
/home/.../src/com/.../controller/servlet/VideoServlet.java
Error:(7, 32) java: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
Error:(13, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class WebServlet
/home/.../src/com/.../service/CustomUserDetailsService.java
Warning:(10, 51) java: org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl in org.springframework.security.core.authority has been deprecated
/home/ldurazo/git/arcofi/arcofi/src/com/arcofi/controller/FileDownloadController.java
Error:(35, 40) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getServletContext()
  location: variable request of type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

I have the library `servlet-api2.3.jar`

And in the project structure i have the following problems

```
Module project : invalid item 'org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0' in the dependencies list
Module project : invalid item 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container' in the dependencies list
Module project : invalid item 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container' in the dependencies list
```

And last, in project structure too:

```
Unknown facet type: 'Spring'
Unknow facet type 'Web'
```

I am using IntelliJ Idea 14 and Eclipse Luna

Comment: Wouldn't be better to start a new project in Idea, adding all the sources, and lib dependencies? How big is this project (how many classes, packages, external depenedencies) ?

Comment: around 80 external jars. I ended doing just that, but i didnt want to encourage that way of doing things so im just adding the dependencies in maven one by one..